# How to change a combobox Value when inserting in database?

Tags: c#

I have created a combobox with items.

Visually in my form the items texts will apear, and i want to change the values to numbers when i insert in the database.

example :

```
        private void contact(){
        TypeAdrCmBx.Items.Add("NPAI");
        TypeAdrCmBx.Items.Add("Personnelle");
        TypeAdrCmBx.Items.Add("Professionelle");
        TypeAdrCmBx.Items.Add("Vacances"); }
```

this is my insert Query :

```
                string Query2 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Adresses] ([Type] ,[Adresse0],[Adresse1],[Adresse2],[CPT],[Ville],[Pays]) VALUES ('" + this.TypeAdrCmBx.Text + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx0.Text + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx1.Text + "','" + this.AdrTxtBx2.Text + "','" + this.CptTxtBx.Text + "','" + this.VilleTxtBx.Text + "','" + this.PaysCmBx0.Text + "')";
```

in the database the combobox values are inserted as numbers :

```
 "NPAI" = 1
 "Personnelle" = 2
 "Professionelle" = 3
 "Vacances" = 4
```

Comment: Did you try Convert.ToInt32()?

Answer (score 0):

On Database side solution,

You need to you 2 tables in database in order to do it. One table will hold strings and values like

X Table

```
ID Number  Value
1    1     "NPAI" 
2    2     "Personnelle"
3    3     "Professionelle"
4    4     "Vacances"
```

and other table you will only use the numbers.
When you want to read them, u will use left join.

On c# side solution.

You can basicly convert them with if,

```
string a="";
if (TypeAdrCmBx.Text.Equals("NPAI"))
    a="1";
else if (TypeAdrCmBx.Text.Equals("Personnelle"))
    a="2";
```

And then simply make the insertion with a.

Hope it helps.